# Prove that $1 \in f'(I)$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $I= (0,2)$, that is $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ and $x=2$ and that $f$ is differentiable on $I$. If $f(0)=1$ and $f(2)=3$ Prove that $1 \in f(I)$

Comment: Do you mean $1\in f'(I)$?

Comment: Hint: use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean $1 \in f'(I)$, this can be done as follows. Compute
$$\frac{2-0}{f(2) - f(0)} = \frac{2}{2} = 1.$$
By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $\xi \in I$ such that $f'(\xi) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).  The result is immediate.